# Отправить только один раз сообщение

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

Пишу бота.
Когда я отправляю ему, к примеру, 3 фотографии он мне 3 раза отправляет сообщение.
Как сделать так что бы он отправил только один раз?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types = ContentType.PHOTO)
async def photo(message: types.Message):
    try:
        for i in range(len(data.ADMINS)):
            await dp.bot.send_photo(data.ADMINS[i], message.photo[0].file_id, caption = message.caption)
        
        await message.answer('Спасибо за ваше сообщение! Вскоре наш Всезнайка осмотрит ваш материал и запостит его, либо займется вашим вопросом и ответит вам. Когда-то. ☺️')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

Comment: А как понять, что пора отправлять сообщение? Может юзер сейчас ещё четвёртую фотографию пришлёт?

Comment: @vp_arth, я хочу что бы каждый раз когда отправляют любое количество фотографий сообщение отправлялось только один раз

Comment: Полагаю нужно ждать(с таймаутом), пока не сменится media_group_id

Comment: у меня та же проблема и не знаю, что делать..